# Another function is not calling after AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

i am calling

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new Loaditems().execute();


    }
```

Now i have other function `loadstatus()` which i have written in

```
protected void onPostExecute(String newdt) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products

    Dialog.dismiss();

    // updating UI from Background Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            loadstatus();
        }
    });
    }
```

But `loadstatus()` is not perfom any action on this postexecute method.

I want to complete `new Loaditems().execute();` this function then and then only i have to call the `loadstatus()` function.

```
private void loastatus() {

flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);

al = new ArrayList<String>();

al.add("php");
// choose your favorite adapter

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
        R.layout.item, R.id.tv_portal, al);

// set the listener and the adapter
flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}
```

doinbackground code:

```
      protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1"));

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_items, "GET",
            params);

    try {
        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {
            // products found
            // Getting Array of Products
            products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

            // looping through All Products
            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable

                name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                // al.add(name);

            }
        } else {

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return null;
}
```

`SwipeFlingAdapterView`  class:

public class SwipeFlingAdapterView extends BaseFlingAdapterView {

```
    private int MAX_VISIBLE = 4;
    private int MIN_ADAPTER_STACK = 6;
    private float ROTATION_DEGREES = 15.f;

    private Adapter mAdapter;
    private int LAST_OBJECT_IN_STACK = 0;
    private onFlingListener mFlingListener;
    private AdapterDataSetObserver mDataSetObserver;
    private boolean mInLayout = false;
    private View mActiveCard = null;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    private FlingCardListener flingCardListener;


    public SwipeFlingAdapterView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SwipeFlingAdapterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.SwipeFlingStyle);
    }

    public SwipeFlingAdapterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SwipeFlingAdapterView, defStyle, 0);
        MAX_VISIBLE = a.getInt(R.styleable.SwipeFlingAdapterView_max_visible, MAX_VISIBLE);
        MIN_ADAPTER_STACK = a.getInt(R.styleable.SwipeFlingAdapterView_min_adapter_stack, MIN_ADAPTER_STACK);
        ROTATION_DEGREES = a.getFloat(R.styleable.SwipeFlingAdapterView_rotation_degrees, ROTATION_DEGREES);
        a.recycle();
    }


    /**
     * A shortcut method to set both the listeners and the adapter.
     *
     * @param context The activity context which extends onFlingListener, OnItemClickListener or both
     * @param mAdapter The adapter you have to set.
     */
    public void init(final Context context, Adapter mAdapter) {
        if(context instanceof onFlingListener) {
            mFlingListener = (onFlingListener) context;
        }else{
            throw new RuntimeException("Activity does not implement SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener");
        }
        if(context instanceof OnItemClickListener){
            mOnItemClickListener = (OnItemClickListener) context;
        }
        setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View getSelectedView() {
        return mActiveCard;
    }


    @Override
    public void requestLayout() {
        if (!mInLayout) {
            super.requestLayout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        // if we don't have an adapter, we don't need to do anything
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }

        mInLayout = true;
        final int adapterCount = mAdapter.getCount();

        if(adapterCount == 0) {
            removeAllViewsInLayout();
        }else {
            View topCard = getChildAt(LAST_OBJECT_IN_STACK);
            if(mActiveCard!=null && topCard!=null && topCard==mActiveCard) {
                removeViewsInLayout(0, LAST_OBJECT_IN_STACK);
                layoutChildren(1, adapterCount);
            }else{
                // Reset the UI and set top view listener
                removeAllViewsInLayout();
                layoutChildren(0, adapterCount);
                setTopView();
            }
        }

        mInLayout = false;

        if(adapterCount < MAX_VISIBLE) mFlingListener.onAdapterAboutToEmpty(adapterCount);
    }


    private void layoutChildren(int startingIndex, int adapterCount){
        while (startingIndex < Math.min(adapterCount, MAX_VISIBLE) ) {
            View newUnderChild = mAdapter.getView(startingIndex, null, this);
            if (newUnderChild.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                makeAndAddView(newUnderChild);
                LAST_OBJECT_IN_STACK = startingIndex;
            }
            startingIndex++;
        }
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    private void makeAndAddView(View child) {

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        addViewInLayout(child, 0, lp, true);

        final boolean needToMeasure = child.isLayoutRequested();
        if (needToMeasure) {
            int childWidthSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(getWidthMeasureSpec(),
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + lp.leftMargin + lp.rightMargin,
                    lp.width);
            int childHeightSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(getHeightMeasureSpec(),
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom() + lp.topMargin + lp.bottomMargin,
                    lp.height);
            child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
        } else {
            cleanupLayoutState(child);
        }


        int w = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();

        int gravity = lp.gravity;
        if (gravity == -1) {
            gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
        }


        int layoutDirection = getLayoutDirection();
        final int absoluteGravity = Gravity.getAbsoluteGravity(gravity, layoutDirection);
        final int verticalGravity = gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;

        int childLeft;
        int childTop;
        switch (absoluteGravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) {
            case Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL:
                childLeft = (getWidth() + getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()  - w) / 2 +
                        lp.leftMargin - lp.rightMargin;
                break;
            case Gravity.END:
                childLeft = getWidth() + getPaddingRight() - w - lp.rightMargin;
                break;
            case Gravity.START:
            default:
                childLeft = getPaddingLeft() + lp.leftMargin;
                break;
        }
        switch (verticalGravity) {
            case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
                childTop = (getHeight() + getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom()  - h) / 2 +
                        lp.topMargin - lp.bottomMargin;
                break;
            case Gravity.BOTTOM:
                childTop = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - h - lp.bottomMargin;
                break;
            case Gravity.TOP:
            default:
                childTop = getPaddingTop() + lp.topMargin;
                break;
        }

        child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + w, childTop + h);
    }




    /**
    *  Set the top view and add the fling listener
    */
    private void setTopView() {
        if(getChildCount()>0){

            mActiveCard = getChildAt(LAST_OBJECT_IN_STACK);
            if(mActiveCard!=null) {

                flingCardListener = new FlingCardListener(mActiveCard, mAdapter.getItem(0),
                        ROTATION_DEGREES, new FlingCardListener.FlingListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCardExited() {
                                mActiveCard = null;
                                mFlingListener.removeFirstObjectInAdapter();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void leftExit(Object dataObject) {
                                mFlingListener.onLeftCardExit(dataObject);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void rightExit(Object dataObject) {
                                mFlingListener.onRightCardExit(dataObject);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(Object dataObject) {
                                if(mOnItemClickListener!=null)
                                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClicked(0, dataObject);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {
                                mFlingListener.onScroll(scrollProgressPercent);
                            }
                        });

                mActiveCard.setOnTouchListener(flingCardListener);

            }
        }
    }

    public FlingCardListener getTopCardListener() throws NullPointerException{
        if(flingCardListener==null){
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        return flingCardListener;
    }

    public void setMaxVisible(int MAX_VISIBLE){
        this.MAX_VISIBLE = MAX_VISIBLE;
    }

    public void setMinStackInAdapter(int MIN_ADAPTER_STACK){
        this.MIN_ADAPTER_STACK = MIN_ADAPTER_STACK;
    }

    @Override
    public Adapter getAdapter() {
        return mAdapter;
    }


    @Override
    public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
        if (mAdapter != null && mDataSetObserver != null) {
            mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
            mDataSetObserver = null;
        }

        mAdapter = adapter;

        if (mAdapter != null  && mDataSetObserver == null) {
            mDataSetObserver = new AdapterDataSetObserver();
            mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
    }

    public void setFlingListener(onFlingListener onFlingListener) {
        this.mFlingListener = onFlingListener;
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener){
        this.mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }




    @Override
    public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs) {
        return new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(getContext(), attrs);
    }


    private class AdapterDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            requestLayout();
        }

    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject);
    }

    public interface onFlingListener {
        public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter();
        public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject);
        public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject);
        public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter);
        public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent);
    }


}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: post doInBackground code also.

Comment: updated  doinbackground code

Answer (score 2):

`onPostExecute` is already in UI thread, so there is no need to call with `runOnUiThread`.

Just write `loadstatus();` instead of

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            loadstatus();
        }
    });
```

Also note that if you cancel `AsyncTask` , `onPostExecute` won't be called.

Comment: i have just do like this but that function is calling but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `runOnUiThread` inside of your `onPostExecute()` method. Call your function directly.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String newdt) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
    Dialog.dismiss();

    loadstatus();

}
```

Comment: i have just added like this and it is calling function but display anything from that function. i have put that function.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong inside of your function. Try to Log something from inside your function and see if it works.

Comment: i have debug that function also.  it is working perfect but dont know why it is not display. !!!

Comment: Oh. Then there must be something wrong with how you have set up your adapter and your `SwipeFlingAdapterView` .

Comment: have updated the `SwipeFlingAdapterView`  class in my question.

Comment: have you checked this? i am still not getting any thing.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use UI thread in OnPostExecuste method...
Please remove the runUIThread and call the loadstatus(); method...

Answer (score 0):

Are you Getting any Exceptions or Error? 
You will have to remove that UI Thread.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String newdt) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products

    Dialog.dismiss();
    loadstatus();
    }
```